# Add condition in contain in cakephp 3 pagination

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

How can i add a condition in contain to paginate in Cakephp3.

This is my code :

```
$this->paginate = [
'contain' => ['Users', 'AssignDrivers.Users', 'Invoices']
];
$bookings = $this->paginate($this->Bookings);   
$this->set(compact('bookings'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['bookings']);
```

For example Something like this:

`$this->paginate($this->bookings)->where(['Bookings.status'=>'pending', 'AssignDrivers.name LIKE'=>'%John%']);`

Thank you for help.

Comment: One way is to pass a query object to the paginate function instead of a model. So, like `$query = this->Bookings->find()->where(...)->contain(...); $bookings = $this->paginate($query);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a condition inside paginate() method.

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['Users', 'AssignDrivers.Users', 'Invoices']
];

$bookings = $this->paginate(
    $this->Bookings->find()->where([
        'Bookings.status'=>'pending', 
        'AssignDrivers.name LIKE'=>'%John%'
    ])
);   

$this->set(compact('bookings'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['bookings']);
```